# Let $f(x)=13x-3$. Find the sum of all possible values of $x$ satisfying $f(x)\cdot f^{-1}(x)=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Let $f(x)=13x-3$. Find the sum of all possible values of $x$
> satisfying $f(x)\cdot f^{-1}(x)=0$.

What I have tried is that I solved for $f^{-1}$, and because $y=13x-3$, $x=\frac{y+3}{13}$, and so when I plug it in, $(13x-3)(\frac{x+3}{13})=0$, and so I got $x=\frac{3}{13}, -3$, and so the sum should be $-\frac{36}{13}$.

However, the answer key said $6$. Am I wrong, or is the answer key wrong? If the answer key is wrong (and I'm pretty sure it is), how is it even possible (by error) to get a $6$?

Comment: Your work looks fine so I'd say the answer key's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct. But if the question was supposed to be

$$ f(x)=\frac{1}{3}x-3 $$

then you get $6$ as the answer.